# Changing selected item in dropdown menu when redirected

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am working on page with ads. I have made one tpl page and I just want to change the order and number of ads on page, when user selects what he wants.

```
<select id="order" class="form-control" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
        <option selected value="http://localhost:8080/newer_older/{{num}}/1">Newer to oldernar</option>
        <option value="http://localhost:8080/older_newer/{{num}}/1">Older to newer</option>
</select>

<select id="num" class="form-control" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
        <option selected value="http://localhost:8080/{{order}}/5/1">5</option>
        <option value="http://localhost:8080/{{order}}/10/1">10</option>
        <option value="http://localhost:8080/{{order}}/all/1">All</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        location.href=document.getElementById("selectbox").value;
    }       
</script>
```

So far I came to this solution: I have two drop down menus with selected items, which will be "primarily" choosen when redirected to this site with ads. Then I found a code, that will redirect user to page with choosen order and number of ads, but I have a problem with the drop down menu. I want it to change the selected value to the one the user choose (so if the user chooses the order from older to newer, the site will redirect to the one he wants, but in the drop down menu, the choosen will still be the primarily choosen, in my case the newer to older order). I want it to work like on [this site](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=node%3D2649513011&field-keywords=friends), where you have in top right corner sort by.

I don't know how to fix this. I am a beginner in html programming, so I don't even know, if this is the right method for this kind of site. I was suggested the `select2`, but I don't know how to work with that.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: So if i get this right, a user visits your page. Then the user gets immediately redirected to the preselected combobox value. And if the user changes the 'new-old-combobox' you it has to be selected at that value the next time the user visits your page?

Comment: No. Everytime the user opens the page I want the preselected combo. Then if user decides for different order and selects it in the drop-box, then he gets redirected to the same page, only the order of ads is different (and the html address).

Comment: So this is in an angular application? Can you show some more of the JavaScript code? For example where does `{{num}}` and `{{order}}` get set?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.. not a very clean way though.

```
<select id="order" class="form-control" onchange="onOrderChange();">
        <option id="newer_older" value="newer_older">
          Newer to older
          </option>
        <option id="older_newer" value="older_newer">
          Older to newer
        </option>
</select>

<select id="num" class="form-control" onchange="onNumChange();">
        <option id="5" value="5">5</option>
        <option id="10" value="10">10</option>
        <option id="all" value="all">All</option>
</select>

<script>
    function onOrderChange() {
        var orderSort = document.getElementById("order").value;
      var num = document.getElementById("num").value;

      if(orderSort == "new_older") {
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/newer_older/" + num + "/1?orderSort=new_older&num=" + num;
        location.href = url;

      } else if(orderSort == "older_newer") {
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/older_newer/" + num + "/1?orderSort=older_newer&num=" + num;
        location.href = url;
      }
    }

    function onNumChange() {
      var orderSort = document.getElementById("order").value;
      var num = document.getElementById("num").value;

      if(num == "5") {
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/" + orderSort + "/5/1?num=5&orderSort=" + orderSort;
        location.href = url;
      } else if (num == "10"){
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/" + orderSort + "/10/1?num=10&orderSort=" + orderSort;
        location.href = url;
      } else if (num == "all"){
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/" + orderSort + "/all/1?num=all&orderSort=" + orderSort;
        location.href = url;
      }
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      var url = new URL(window.location.href);

      var selectedOrder = url.searchParams.get("orderSort");
      var selectedNum = url.searchParams.get("num");

      if(selectedOrder != null) {
        document.getElementById(selectedOrder).selected=true;
      }

      if(selectedNum != null){
        document.getElementById(selectedNum).selected=true;
      }
    };
</script>
```